# iOSでframeworkを複数内包したframeworkを作りたい

Tags: ios, framework

frameworkA, frameworkBを含んだframeworkCを作りたいです。
※framework = Cocoa Touch Frameworkのことを指しております。

調べたところこのカタチはumbrella frameworkと呼ばれ
下記手順を参考に試してみましたが
出来上がったframeworkCを実際に使用するプロジェクトに導入すると
内包しているframeworkA,frameworkBが見つからないエラーが出ます。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk

おそらく参照可能にする設定を入れる必要があるという当たりはついているのですが
どこでどう設定すれば良いかが現状わかっておりません。
ご教授頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いします。

環境:Xcode 8.1

Comment: 技術的に可能ですが、ネストしたフレームワークを使用しているとAppStoreの審査に提出することができません。それでもネストしたフレームワークを作る必要がありますか？個人で使うだけとか、エンタープライズ用のプロファイルで配付するという以外には使えませんが、それでも本当にネストしたフレームワークを使いたいですか？

Comment: AppStoreの審査に提出できないのは知りませんでした。
ネストさせた方が1つを導入するだけで済むので、楽になるだろうな、というところからのこの質問でした。
各フレームワークをそれぞれ導入する方法ですすめます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: おっしゃる通りで、依存するフレームワークなどは含めてしまえると導入が簡単になります。そのためRealmなどでも過去に試みましたが、AppStoreに出せない問題が解決できないので断念しました。